# Bootstrap Tab shows but does not highlight until clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using Twitter Bootstrap (v3.0.3) Tabs, and they are working perfectly except... the tab that I have marked as `active` does not visually highlight unless you click on it.

The interesting thing is I can reproduce this behavior using jsFiddle and the example code from the Twitter Bootstrap website:

Bootstrap Example: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXV56/

**Example Tab Code:**

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Note in jsFiddle that the `active` tab is open but not visually highlighted.  If you move the `active` css class to a different tab, and set some kind of content so you can tell them apart, you'll see that Bootstrap is reading that class and opening the correct  tab by default, it's just not highlighting it...  If you click on any tab, including the currently active one, the visual cue shows up highlighting the tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap Tabs consist of two separate components: the tab-navigation (`ul.nav.nav-tabs > li > a`) and the tab contents (`div.tab-content > div.tab-pane`).

You have to activate both components for this to work, because `div.tab-pane.active` is used for displaying the correct tab-pane. The visual cue in the menu is managed by the `li.active > a`.

So, change your example to this, and everything works OK.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I figured it out right about the time you posted by reviewing other examples.  I've suggested the fix to the official documentation: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/12260