# Tabs not highlighting on page open,

Tags: html

I've been working at this, unfortunately I can't get the tab to be highlighted when the page loads.

I have tried using other suggestions in stack overflow such as jquery and window.onload, but none of these solutions work.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-active-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-active" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-active" aria-selected="true">ACTIVE</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-notactive-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-notactive" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-notactive" aria-selected="false">INACTIVE</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-pending-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-pending" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-pending" aria-selected="false">PENDING</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

  <div class="tab-pane active in" id="nav-active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-active-tab">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
```

Comment: what do you mean by " tab to be highlighted" ?

Comment: I guess a better word would be the tab color does not show as active. If I click on the tabs they highlight/show as active, but the Active tab is the one the page opens to, it simply will not highlight unless clicked.

Comment: So, I suppose there is some CSS ? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169929/bootstrap-tab-shows-but-does-not-highlight-until-clicked THIS is the same issue I am having it seems, I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

simply do (javascript)

```js
document.querySelector('a[data-toggle]').focus()
```

Comment: I am using typescript and getting errors for ('a[data-toggle]').focus()

Comment: @KMolls   and how could I have guessed that (or other information) on your question? please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought that I could manipulate it for typescript. Sorry for that confusion. This is my first post so I am definitely learning - I will look through the link you provided!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue in case anyone needs it...
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" on the one you want the tab to show active.

Comment: If this solved your issue, then please accept your answer by clicking the green checkmark next to your answer to mark it as accepted and possibly help future visitors.